System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory, in SaveChangesAsync Method of EF Core
I am performing a really simple operation of Insert using the Entity Framework in Azure Function but unable to understand why I am getting the error. Below is the code snippets of different files:
LoggingMiddleware.cs
public class LoggingMiddleware : ILoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly AppsContext _context;

    public LoggingMiddleware(AppsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task LogRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var requestHeaders = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, httpContext.Request.Headers.Select(header => $"{header.Key} = {header.Value}"));
            using var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body);
            string requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var httpRequestApiLog = new HttpRequestApiLog
            {
                Url = httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl(),
                RequestMethod = httpContext.Request.Method,
                RequestHeaders = requestHeaders,
                RequestBody = requestBody
            };

            _context.HttpRequestApiLogs.Add(httpRequestApiLog);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

Azure Function:
private readonly ILoggingMiddleware _loggingMiddleware;

public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    await _loggingMiddleware.LogRequestAsync(req.HttpContext);
    // Other lines of code
}

Exception happens at line:
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

And the below file is opened which I have no idea what it is doing and throwing the exception. Below snip is from file SNINativeMethodWrapper.cs
What should I do to fix this issue and keep myself rolling further? Stuck on this issue since 2 days and tried all possible answers on the internet.

